# Expo/React Native: Why is the iOS simulator different from a real iPhone?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, ios-simulator

I have been making an money management app. I am using Expo and React Native. I have been using the iOS simulator (specifically the iPhone7) to see how the app looks after I have made changes to the code. I am happy with the look of the app on the iOS simulator.

To my knowledge, the app looks fine on the Expo Go app on Android devices.

I also have the expo app installed on my actual iPhone7. I just used it to test my app on a real phone. However, it appears that some elements appear different from those in the simulator. You can see the difference in the screenshots attached below. To my knowledge, these two shouldn't differ. Does anyone know what I can do to resolve this?

[Here is an image of my simulator running the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcedE.png)

[Here is a screenshot from my iPhone7 running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhhSt.png)

Comment: Do you have an accessibility feature (specifically dynamic type) set on your device?

Comment: @jnpdx you are right, the "Larger Text" accessibility setting messes with my app. I will look into an override